# Trouble getting rotated text to render properly in print styles

Tags: css, rotatetransform

So I have this code for an h2 that is rotated

```
<h2>An Internet Marketing Company</h2>
```

Here is the css for both the regular and print stylesheets

Regular

```
.proposal .page.cover h2 {
    color: #ddd;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    margin: 40px 0 0 20px;
}
```

Print

```
.proposal .page.cover h2 {
    color: #ddd !important;
}
```

So the result on the webpage is correct as it looks like this
http://gyazo.com/0e41e9e7762e1e15bfc3a6d26e1c1c1a

The problem occurs when I try to print it to PDF
http://gyazo.com/a3d9b58b98f08cc81dd312ec4a7afa27

There seems to be this black outline gunk going around the text. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What are you using to generate the PDF?

Comment: Print function in chrome